# Create boolean field in QGIS graphic modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is there a way to create a boolean field within a model in the QGIS graphic modeler?

I want to run a QGIS model that, if it doesn't exist already, creates and fills a boolean field for a vector layer based on a case statement, similar to this one:

```
CASE
WHEN "another_field" = 'example_value' THEN true
ELSE false
END
```

In the normal field calculator I can simply choose boolean as a field type:
[image: Boolean field type in normal field calculator]

But then, when within the graphic modeler I only have the possibility to select from string or number field types for the field calculator output:
[image: Only string and number field types in graphic modeler field calculator]

Also, I tried fiddling around with the other options in the graphic modeler (e.g. first creating a field and then running the field calculator), but as far as I can tell all of them only offer this limited selection of field types.

So, does anybody know if there is any way to create a boolean output field from within in a graphic modeler workflow?

Comment: As far as I know it is impossible by now, maybe a String is okay for you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345947/using-boolean-parameter-in-qgis-graphic-modeler. What is your input data source type, is it GeoPackage?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!
Unfortunately the output field is required to be a boolean because of an involved third party.
And yes, the input layer is either from a GeoPackage or from a PostgreSQL database.